# Uploading a Blob to Azure storage doesnt work for local development emulator using NodeJs

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, blobstorage

I am trying to upload a local file to blob storage using NodeJs. The server sends me the following details

```
{hostName: "StorageAccount", containerName:"containerName", "blobName": blobName, sasToken: "sasToken"}
```

and following is the code written for uploading the file

```
var azure = require('azure-storage');
var blobSvc = azure.createBlobServiceWithSas(result.hostName,result.sasToken);
blobSvc.createBlockBlobFromLocalFile(result.containerName,result.blobName,'server.json', 
function(error, result, response){
  if(!error){
   // file uploaded
 }
});
```

above code works fine if its a real storage information in Azure, but throws "Specified resource not found" error if its on local development storage.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Can you share your SAS Token? Also, please tell us the value you're setting for `result.hostName`.

Comment: result.hostName is http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstorageAccount1 if its development, else its https://xxxx..blob.core.windows.net

Answer (score 1):

To develop with Azure Storage Emulator in Node.js, please make sure you have start the local emulator first (refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-emulator/ for more), and try to leverage [`generateDevelopmentStorageCredentials()`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/master/lib/azure-storage.js#L20), which creates a connection string that can be used to create a service which runs on the storage emulator. The emulator must be downloaded separately.

Here is the code snippet:

```
var azure = require('azure-storage');
var fs = require('fs');

var devStoreCreds = azure.generateDevelopmentStorageCredentials();
var blobsrv = azure.createBlobService(devStoreCreds);

blobsrv.createContainerIfNotExists('container', {
  publicAccessLevel: 'blob'
}, function(error, result, response) {
  if (!error) {
    blobsrv.createBlockBlobFromLocalFile('container', <blobname>, <filepath>, function (error, result, response) {
            if (!error) {
                console.log("Uploaded" + result);
            }
            else {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }); 
  }else{
    console.log(error)
  }
})
```

Comment: I had the Storage emulator running. The information about Blob is provided by another application running in the same machine.

Comment: Do you still have the issue after trying my code snippet? And could you please provide your `result` info of emulator